# Can a renaming on an iOS application be done in one locale only?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an iOS app that's used internationally.
This app supports push-notifications.

The app is used internationally.
however, recent legal problems force me to change its name in the U.S.
I don't want to change its name globally, just the U.S.

Whta's the minimal set of action I can take to get there as fast as I can?

Can I change the application name and some of its UI for a certain locale only? (ENG-US)
do must I deploy a new app altogether alongside the old one?
Note I must keep the "british" locale with the old UI, but must rename the application name and change some of its UI only for the U.S.

Is that possible? or will I be forced to deploy a new app just for the U.S.?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName are [localizable](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/15/localize-iphone-application-name.html). You need to add your localizations in an InfoPlist.strings file and add specific localizations there.

Comment: so If I do that, my application name will be different on the US app store, than it will on the UK app store? According to the court ruling, my app name needs to change in the U.S. only, that also means U.S users will have to "see" the new name when looking for it in the AppStore.